# auto hot key and verifying responce

Tags: autohotkey

I am automating a simple text based .exe running in a cmd  window on win 7

We have scripts written in Auto hot key

It's kinda like a blind man is typing them in, no error checking whatsoever
Auto Hot Key is very reliable, but we need some smarts based upon what is returned

Any way to get Auto Hot key to monitor for "OK" after every SendInput?
I am not seeing this capability

An example or suggestion would be great

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

There are a few places where you can start.

First, take a look at `process` in the docs, where you can get the `PID` of your application.  You can also get it using autohotkey's own `run` command.

Second, working on a cmd window can be tricky.  There are a few ahk libraries out there that you can use:

- [`STDOUTTOVAR`](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/15455-stdouttovar/) - which grabs the console's output into a text variable where you can parse it using ahk string functions.
- [`CONSOLEAPP`](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/31569-retrieve-standard-output-stdout-of-a-program/) - redirect and capture standard output.
- [`CMDret_stream`](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/7874-cmdret-ahk-functions/) - stream and store cmd output

There are not any simple built-in functions in ahk to do this easily; you have to resort to the elaborate implementations of the libraries (or build your own).